# Cant seem to retrieve info on django many to many, 'object has no attribute'

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

In my app, I have a custom defined 'Group_Set' model, designed to group users together.  I can't seem to retrieve the users in the groups though.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'avatars/', default = 'avatars/default.jpg')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    public = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

class Group_Sets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')
    public = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

Once we get a Group_Set object, group = get_object_or_404(), all the other attributes work.  However, group.users returns 'auth.User.none' even though I can see the relationship function in the database, and in the admin.

Can anyone see anything wrong with how I've set this up?

Comment: It's not clear what code you are running and what result you get. Have you tried `group.users.all()`? See the docs on [many to many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This was a dumb mistake on my part, you need to use 'group.users.all()', so theres that.  Remember your related_name, and the all method.